# php piping to a program ( get the vars) convert back to an email fomat with no headers etc

Tags: php, email, pipe

I can pipe to a program but how do I convert the email so the code can be emailed and read by email clients?  I can email it but its full of other chars. How can i get it without all the extra messy code showing up on page. I just want the email in its old format that can be read in an email. I need this to read both html and tex.

```
 #!/usr/bin/php –q
<? 
     $fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r"); 
    while (!feof($fd)) {
     $email .= fread($fd, 1024); }


    $to = "someone@example.com";

    $subject = "Test mail";

    $message = $email;

    $from = "someonelse@example.com";

    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); ?>
```

Comment: That's hard to say if you make people guess how the input looks like.

Comment: Not sure what extra messy code you're seeing because it works okay for me.

Comment: LOOKS LIKE THIS:

"From  Wed Apr 20 13:36:11 2011
Received: from mail-iw0-f172.google.com ([209.85.214.172])
by with esmtps (TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128)
(Exim 4.69)
(envelope-from <>)
id 1QCcG3-000491-HJ
for  Wed, 20 Apr 2011 13:36:11 -0500
Received: by iwn39 with SMTP id 39so1421176iwn.17
 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=20cf303bffa0f73af404a15de5d6

--20cf303bffa0f73af404a15de5d6
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

hello

Answer (score 0):

Those are just e-mail headers, some of them added by the esmtp-server or any other servers in between. Is does not have to do with messy code, it's the misinterpretation of the headers by the client.

Comment: How do I get the client to read it?  I sent that from an email.  When I send that same email to another email it works. If I pipe it thru and email it then it doesn't.

Comment: Parse the headers in your loop, don't append to $email, but validate the incoming headers and convert them to HTTP-headers where needed.